# AWS Sagemaker - PCA Model doesn't deploy

Tags: python, jupyter, pca, amazon-sagemaker

I've created a PCA Model in SageMaker..something along those lines:

```
pca = PCA(role=role,
             train_instance_count=1,
             train_instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
             output_path=output_path, 
             num_components=N_COMPONENTS, 
             sagemaker_session=session)
```

Then I've fitted it against my data

```
pca.fit(data)
```

And finally I would like to deploy the model, but when I run:

```
pca_predictor = pca.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, 
                              instance_type='ml.t2.medium')
```

I see this error message:

> TypeError: create_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model_kms_key'

I have no idea how to understand that error and what it refers to...any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade sagemaker, I was getting this error with version 1.42.6. It's fixed in 1.42.9

Run the command:

```
    ! pip install --upgrade sagemaker
```

If using a jupyter notebook instance you may need to restart the kernel to pick up the change.

To check the current sagemaker version use:

```
    print(sagemaker.__version__)
```

Comment: Please provide the example how this can be achieved or how did you update.

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh In a cell above the cell where you run the `import sagemaker` command run,

`! pip install --upgrade sagemaker`
Then in the dropdown options available at the top click on "Kernel" >>> "Restart". Now in a cell right below where you have imported sagemaker, run,
`print(sagemaker.__version__)`
This should show a version equal to or greater than 1.42.9.

Comment: @akileshraj Thank you and I believe the user already edited in his answer.